Нет выбора ОС при запуске
На ноутбуке установлены Windows 10 и Ubuntu.
Раньше все работало отлично и стабильно.
Вчера загрузил Ubuntu для проверки обновлений. В процессе обновления ноутбук перезагрузился сам и теперь нет возможности выбора ОС при запуске.
То есть Ubuntu загружается автоматом. Допуск к файлам windows сохранился.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть шанс исправить ситуацию?
Спасибо!

Да, windows остался, надо только загрузчик починить. У вас был Grub?

Можете попробовать тул Boot-Repair

да, был Grub, судя по описанию)

Там разные ситуации возможны, ну попробуйте boot-repair или если не поможет можно переустановить grub с liveusb

boot repair помог!! Урааа)) Спасибо!
